# Unrecognized option "google" under "security.firewalls.secured_area.oauth"

Tags: symfony, google-oauth

Am trying to implement Google login for my website using Symfony `HWIOAuthBundle`

My problem:

> Unrecognized option "google" under
>   "security.firewalls.secured_area.oauth"

my client_id and client_secret are good and received from Google, I just don't pasted it because of privacy.

Am using this [HWIOAuthBundle Documentation](https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle)

```
hwi_oauth:
    firewall_names: [secured_area]
    resource_owners:
        any_name:
            type:                google
            client_id:           myid
            client_secret:       mysecret
            scope:               "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login"
            options:
                request_visible_actions: "http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity http://schemas.google.com/CommentActivity"
```

my `Security.yml` file:

security:

```
# http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
providers:
    in_memory:
        memory: ~

firewalls:
    # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs

    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    #main:
    default:

        anonymous: ~
        http_basic: ~
        # activate different ways to authenticate

        # http_basic: ~
        # http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#a-configuring-how-your-users-will-authenticate

        # form_login: ~
        # http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/form_login_setup.html

#access_control:
    # require ROLE_ADMIN for /main*
   # - { path: ^/main, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }

    secured_area:

      anonymous: ~
      oauth:
         resource_owners:

         google:             "/login/check-google"

         login_path:        /login
         use_forward:       false
         failure_path:      /login

         oauth_user_provider:

            service: my.oauth_aware.user_provider.service

access_control:
          - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

Comment: Can you past your security.yml file?
the error said you have an issue under security.firewalls.secured_area.oauth

Comment: I pasted, could you help me.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In your security.ym the `google` option should be under `resource_owners`, you have to add a tab space and it should work.

```
 resource_owners:
      google:           "/login/check-google"
```

Comment: `The service definition "my.oauth_aware.user_provider.service" does not exist.` Now I need to define my service in `service.yml` file?

Comment: Am very confused about it, is it correct?

`services:

    my.oauth_aware.user_provider.service:

        class:      HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle\HWIOAuthBundle
        arguments: ['hwi_oauth.user.provider', { google: client_id }]`